# Extremely New to SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am struggling struggling with my code. I would love some help. Am I thinking about this the right way? I have a huge table and I want to extract that data from certain dates. My two dates: 1969-12-01 and 1948-01-01 my sample code:

```
data null;
 call symput ('timenow',put (time(),time.));
 call symput ('datenow',put (date(),date9.)); 
run; 
title "The current time is timenow and the date is datenow"; 
proc print data=sashelp.buy; 
run;
```

Comment: You need to explain more what you are trying to do.  Does you dataset have a variable that stores the date?  How is the date stored?  Is it a date variable? datetime variable? string variable?  What do you want out? A report? A new dataset?

Comment: I just want to create a separate database with the dates above

Answer (score 0):

So first learn about your dataset.  So for example run PROC CONTENTS.

```
proc contents data=sashelp.buy; run;
```

Which will show you that there is variable named DATE that has date values (number of days since 1960).

So to reference a specific date use a date literal.  That is a quoted string in the style that the DATE informat can read followed by the letter D.  You can then use a WHERE statement to filter the data.

```
data want;
  set sashelp.buy;
  where date = '31dec1969'd ;
run;
```

Which will not find any observations since that date does not appear in that dataset.

If you want to select for multiple dates you could either add more conditions using OR.

```
  where (date = '31dec1969'd) or (date = '01jan1948'd);
```

You can also use the IN operator:

```
  where date in ('31dec1969'd '01jan1948'd);
```

Note that if your variable contains datetime values (number of seconds) then to pick a specific date you would either need to use a range of datetime literals:

```
  where datetime between '31dec1969:00:00'dt and '31dec1969:11:59:59'dt);
```

Or convert the number of seconds into number of days and compare to the date literal.

```
  where datepart(datetime) = '31dec1969'd ;
```

Comment: I just want to make sure I have this correctly: data want;
  set name of table;
 where date in ('31dec1969'd '01jan1948'd);
 
run;

Comment: Yes, assuming that DATE is the name of your variable and that it actually has date values and not something else, like datetime values or even character strings.

Comment: That will give me the info for 1948-1969?

Comment: No.  That is not what you asked for and not what the code is doing.  If you want to check for a range of values the test needs to reflect that. For example you could use the BETWEEN syntax that WHERE statements allow  `where date between '01jan1948'd and '31dec1969'd;`

Comment: I do apologize Tom. Does this look correct: data want;
  set name of table;
where date between '01jan1948'd and '31dec1969'd; 
run;

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Sportsguy3090.

Here I make a dataset called sample with some sample dates.  That dataset has a variable called name and another variable called date.  Internally, SAS stores dates as the number of days until or after January 1st 1970.  That is rough to look at.  So I use the format statement to have the dates appear as a 10 character string with month/day/year.

```
data sample;    
    name = "Abe  "; date = "01Dec1969"d; output;
    name = "Betty"; date = "01Jan1948"d; output;
    name = "Carl"; date = "06Jun1960"d; output;
    name = "Doug"; date = "06Dec1969"d; output;
    name = "Ed"; date = "01Jan1947"d; output;

    format date mmddyy10.; 
run;
```

The code below subsets the data and puts the good records into a new dataset called keepers. It only keeps the records that are in the date range (including the limit dates).

```
data keepers;
    set sample;
    where date between "01jan1948"d and "01Dec1969"d;
run;
```

I hope that helps.... if not send up another flare.